# View nicely formatted version of HTML source

Tags: dom, text-editor, notepad++, text-formatting

I need to edit this HTML page and re-upload it.

The problem is that somehow all of the newlines have been eliminated from it so that its just one long line.  I'm using Notepad++ now, although I don't have to be.

What is a good way to view and edit this HTML/PHP/Javascript source in a way that a reasonable human being can read it?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Do a search for 'code beautifier' or 'code optimizer'. Otherwise selecting long empty spaces and doing replace with '\n' in extended mode in Notepad++ will work, but if length of empty spaces between tag is inconsistent it can take a bit. Not too long though.

Comment: Might be the difference between Unix and DOS line endings, you can browse around the options for notepad++ (maybe look in save as or in the status bar at the bottom) and try changing the text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tidy this up (as @AR suggested) with notepad++.  Go into Notepad++, go to the plugin manager and select
[textFX](http://textfx.no-ip.com/textfx/) and install that.

among other things, it will install a new menu item in the toolbar called "textFX"
select it, then select Text Fx HTML Tidy.  This will give you a selection of formatting objects and ought to pretty it up for you.

once again:

> TextFx >> TextFx HTML Tidy